# What is the meaning of the phrase - "A function f(n) can be represented is the order of g(n) that is O(g(n))"?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to learn analysis and design of algorithm through online tutorials and reading materials and right now I'm  trying to learn asymptotic notation.
While browsing through some online notes I came across this phrase  - "A function f(n) can be represented is the order of g(n) that is O(g(n))" which I was unable to grasp and now I'm stuck because of this.
Can anyone explain to what this phrase actually means ?

You can checkout the article from where I read it if you find it confusing.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms_asymptotic_notations_apriori.htm

Comment: That phrase has grammatical issues. Are you sure about "is"? NB: do not put phrases in all CAPS. It is considered shouting.

Comment: I made some changes in the question, are these ok? If not can you suggest some?

Comment: Where did you get the quoted phrase from? Can you add more context? Link maybe to a document where you quote this from?

Comment: Thanks for adding the source of the quote. That article has several issues with proper grammar. It also has *"there exists a value of positive integer n"*. This sounds as if this phrase was translated from another language..

Comment: Yeah I was getting very confused  because of the grammar. In the end I switched sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar of the sentence is incorrect: *"can be represented is"* makes no sense. So it is hard to say what the intention is of this phrase, but it could be something like this:

> A function *f(n)* can represent the order of *g(n)*, that is *O(g(n))*.

Which in more elaborate terms could be understood as:

> When a function *f(n)* represents the order of *g(n)*, then we note that as *f(n) = O(g(n))*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) defines when a function *f(x)* is *O(g(x))*:

> if the absolute value of *f(x)* is at most a positive constant multiple of *g(x)* for all sufficiently large values of *x*.

The rest of the Wikipedia entry provides a lot of information about this concept, with several examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we have tow function, f(n), and g(n).
**f(n) = O(g(n))** means that the function **f(n)** is asymptotically less than or equal to the function **g(n)**.[image]

The illustration is from [stackexchange question on f(n) and O(g(n)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42257/why-is-fn-of-class-ogn-in-this-graph).

- A good tutorial on [Khanacademy algorithms asymptotic-notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/asymptotic-notation)
- You can also check the [wikipedia page on Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)